# ASP.net JavaScript não reconhece a TextArea se tiver uma Tag runat="server"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Estou com um problema no meu JavaScript.
Estou a usar um código que server para fazer a numeração numa TextArea quando o utilizador dá Enter, no entanto, se essa `TextArea` tiver a tag `runat="server"` o Javascript não reconhece a caixa e simplesmente não funciona.

Código de JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#objetivos_projeto").keyup(function (event) {
                    if (event.which != 13)
                        return;
                    var elm = $(this);
                    var lines = elm.val().split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
                        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\d+\.\s|^)/, (i + 1) + ". ");
                    elm.val(lines.join("\n"));
                });
            }); 
        </script>
```

Código da TextArea :

```
<textarea id="objetivos_projeto" runat="server" rows="5" cols="32">1. </textarea>
```

No entanto, se retirar a tag `runat="server"` a função de JavaScript já reconhece a `TextArea` e faz o que é suposto fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No asp.net quando você usa `runat="server"` significará que você manipulará o componente no lado do servidor e não no lado do cliente(browser).

Quando isto ocorre, seu **id** que era `objetivos_projeto` o asp.net vai renderizar seu id como ex: `ctl00$objetivos_projeto`.

Para evitar que o asp.net altere seu id, basta você colocar o parâmetro `ClientIDMode="Static"` e então você poderá manter o `runat="server"` normalmente.

Ficaria desta forma:

```
<textarea id="objetivos_projeto" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" rows="5" cols="32">1. </textarea>
```

Comment: Obrigado, foi bastante útil !

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver seu problema, coloque na chamada do seu evento javascript a seguinte linha

> objetivos_projeto.ClientID

para pegar o nome do ID dinamicamente.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#<%=objetivos_projeto.ClientID%>').keyup(function (event) {
                    if (event.which != 13)
                        return;
                    var elm = $(this);
                    var lines = elm.val().split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
                        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\d+\.\s|^)/, (i + 1) + ". ");
                    elm.val(lines.join("\n"));
                });
            }); 
        </script>
```